# Android ScrollView layout isn't working on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, scrollview

I'm trying to create a application with the possibility of changing the screen orientation. On screen orientation change, I want my data to be saved. I created layouts with the same name but a different orientation. The portrait layout is a RelativeLayout. The landscape one has a ScrollView layout that contain the RelativeLayout otherwise the content is exactly the same.
  As I'm using API13 and +, I used this line in my manifest :

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

When I change the orientation, my data are still there but the ScrollView isn't working so I can't access the bottom of my layout.

Without the previous line in the manifest.xml file, the ScrollView works perfectly (but the data are not saved). I tried to change my RelativeLayout into a LinearLayout as it is the most common layout used in a SrollView but it didn't work.

Do you have an idea to solve this problem ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: please check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564737/android-orientation-change-different-layout-same-fragments) may helps you

Comment: I am not sure that it is the best solution. Indeed, my app is very simple and composed of 1 activity. What I understood (maybe I'm wrong) is that fragments are used for complex app. I think that using fragment here is like buying a  Ferrari do to 1mile each day. Again this is just my impression. Do you think there is a more adapted solution ? And if possible, I'd like to understand why it is not working.

Comment: your trying two diff layout file for _normal layout_ and _land layout_ (landscape)?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 layout files (normal & landscape). The layout landscape file has a ScrollView and in this ScrollView, the same code than the normal file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I think it is not the best solution and I still don't understand why the code in my question isn't working. So if you know just post a comment or an answer.
My solution is : 
1) I removed the line in the manifest
2) I implemented these two methods :

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //data to be saved
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        //retore data
    }
```

This solution works because I haven't a lot of data to save and restore. It's more a way to avoid the previous problem than a way to resolve it.
Moreover, this method can be a problem for example if you have an ImageView that should be disabled at the beginning and enabled after an event for the rest of the activity life. If you use the setEnabled(false) method at the beginning of onCreate(), if you change the screen orientation, the setEnabled(false) method will occur again even if the event to change the button state occured before. So you want your button to be enable but after the screen oriantation change it will be disabled. (it's easy to avoid this problem even with this solution, but it's not a clean code).